# Getting error while using cartesian product in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I am trying to make a cartesian product in pentaho by using join rows (cartesian product) . I am using 2 input streams and both have data. But I am getting error:

```
2013/11/22 13:57:31 - Join Rows (cartesian product).0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2013/11/22 13:57:31 - Join Rows (cartesian product).0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2013/11/22 13:57:31 - Join Rows (cartesian product).0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.joinrows.JoinRows.getRowData(JoinRows.java:213)
2013/11/22 13:57:31 - Join Rows (cartesian product).0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.joinrows.JoinRows.outputRow(JoinRows.java:301)
2013/11/22 13:57:31 - Join Rows (cartesian product).0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.joinrows.JoinRows.processRow(JoinRows.java:287)
2013/11/22 13:57:31 - Join Rows (cartesian product).0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
2013/11/22 13:57:31 - Join Rows (cartesian product).0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

How to debug this?

Comment: What version of PDI are you using? I use the `Join rows` step very rarely, but don't remember having this problem. On initial search I don't see a JIRA for it. You might have to enter one. Only other thing I can think of is to get the source and run under Eclipse debugger.

Comment: could somebody do a paste of the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

From your post, I see you are using version 4.4.0-stable. I have often managed to get more helpful error messages from this version using the following trick:

- add a "select fields" step after the buggy step,
- click get fields to select.

If you don't get a more meaningful error message, we would need more details about the two input streams you're trying to join.